# how to pass array across activity with intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

i have code like this, My goals is to pass `viewModel.cart` to secondActivity and submit it to Adapter.

CartModels:

```
data class CartModels (
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val price: Int,
    val qty: Int,
    val subTotal: Int
)
```

MainActivity:

```
btnCheckout.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d("MainActivity:::::", "onViewCreated: ${viewModel.cart}")
    val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), InvoiceActivity::class.java)

    val cart = viewModel.cart.map {
        arrayListOf(
            it.id,
            it.title,
            it.price,
            it.qty,
            it.subTotal
        )
    } as ArrayList<String>

    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(TAG_CART_DATA, cart)
    startActivity(intent)

}
```

first i mapping the `viewModel.cart` to ArrayList because i cant put it directly to `intent`

SecondActivity:

```
val listCart = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(TAG_CART_DATA)?.map {
    CartModels(
        it[0].toInt(),
        it[1].toString(),
        it[2].toInt(),
        it[3].toInt(),
        it[4].toInt(),
    )
}

mAdapter.submitList(listCart)
binding.rvCart.apply {
    adapter = mAdapter
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@InvoiceActivity)
    setHasFixedSize(true)

}
```

then i mapped it again to `CartModels`

when i run the app, i got this error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing your object as an array make your data class serializable and pass in as it is.

Implement the serializable interface.

```
import java.io.Serializable


data class CartModel (
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val price: Int,
    val qty: Int,
    val subTotal: Int
) : Serializable
```

Pass it through the intent

```
 val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), InvoiceActivity::class.java)
 intent.putExtra(TAG_CART_DATA, cart)
```

Invoice Activity

```
val cart = intent.getSerializableExtra(TAG_CART_DATA) as? CartModels
```

Comment: thanks bro., it worked. but i still need to mapping `viewModel.cart` to ArrayList first. because `putExtra` only accept ArrayList

Comment: who said putExtra only accepts arrayList, you can pass in object too as shown in the answer